# Modify the context in Ariadne before the resolvers

Tags: python, graphql, ariadne-graphql

How to modify the content of the `context` before it is passed to the resolver functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout the documentation for the special Ariadne type [ContextValue](https://ariadnegraphql.org/docs/types-reference#contextvalue).

The [GraphQL](https://github.com/mirumee/ariadne/blob/master/ariadne/asgi.py) class accepts a keyword argument `context_value`. It can be of any type and will be set as context.

If a callable is passed, then it will be called with the `request` as an argument.

So:

1. Create a function to build the desired context

   ```
   def get_context_value(request):
       return {'request': request, 'test': "TEST"}
   ```
2. Pass the function at GraphQL initialization:

   ```
   app = GraphQL(
       schema,
       context_value=get_context_value,
       debug=True,
   )
   ```

Context value inside resolvers:

```
{'request': <starlette.requests.Request object at 0x7fc363dbf370>, 'test': 'TEST'}
```